# Mongo nested find for array not picking up object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm doing a find on a nested array object and one of it's property. But the result is null.

This is the document that i'm struggling with.
https://jsonblob.com/78022829-0942-11ea-98b2-cbfc62bce9bf

i'm search for this object with the sub-object "externalAccounts" and it's extId 106100668938302013942.

This is my query:

```
  let user = await UserProfile.findOne({'externalAccounts': {$elemMatch: {extId: id}}});
```

Returning null. I also tried the externalAccounts.extId way but won't work as externalAccounts is an array. Any suggestions?

My Schemas:

==

```
const UserProfileSchema = new Schema(
externalAccounts:[{
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'ExternalAccount',
          default: [],
        }]
}



const ExternalAccountSchema = new Schema(
        {
                type: { type: String },
                extId: { type: String },
                token: {type: String,},
        },
        {        usePushEach: true,}
    ); 
module.exports = Mongoose.model('ExternalAccount', ExternalAccountSchema);
```

Comment: How did you expose UserProfileSchema as a model ? Also why is your schema's defined like that ? I think you might need to merge these two schema or no need to make a model for ExternalAccount?

Comment: Hi @srinivasy  What is wrong with the schema? and why can't i have the external account schema? its just like this. |
module.exports = Mongoose.model('UserProfile', UserProfileSchema);